# How to convert time in seconds Larger than 86400 to human readable by Carbon API extension

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I used the approved answer to this question but carbon does not calculate time correctly.

[laravel-how-to-convert-time-in-seconds-to-human-readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66872145/laravel-how-to-convert-time-in-seconds-to-human-readable)

Why the output of the following codes is different?

```
$sec = 17279645;
Carbon::now()->addSeconds($sec)->diffForHumans(false, ['parts' => 5]);
CarbonInterval::seconds($sec)->cascade()->forHumans();


"6 months 2 weeks 3 days 54 minutes 4 seconds after"
"7 months 3 days 23 hours 54 minutes 5 seconds"
```

Comment: [You can do this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19680778/3536236) (Dupe question).

Comment: I prefer use locales supported by Carbon

Comment: For example, 6 months or 7 months depends entirely on *which* month's your dealing with as months have different day counts.

Comment: Your answer will have a different coding for each language, such as English, French, etc. My goal is to use the carbon translation feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CarbonInterval::cascade() use simple static factors:

```
[
    'milliseconds' => [1000, 'microseconds'],
    'seconds' => [1000, 'milliseconds'],
    'minutes' => [60, 'seconds'],
    'hours' => [60, 'minutes'],
    'dayz' => [24, 'hours'],
    'weeks' => [7, 'dayz'],
    'months' => [4, 'weeks'],
    'years' => [12, 'months'],
]
```

The same number of seconds always give the same output.

While `diffForHumans` takes the "now" into account, months will actually have 28, 30 or 31 days, (a day can be 25 hours if you have DST in your interval etc.) so the same amount of seconds gives you variable output depending on the current time.

About the 1 second difference, it's because between the moment you do `Carbon::now()` and the moment you do `diffForHumans()` few microseconds elapsed. So your interval is actually something like 17279644.987 instead of exactly 17279645.